# Timer class which send notification to all registered classes.Which design pattern is preferred?

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, design-patterns

I have timer Thread class which invokes all registers classes methods  for every 5 sec.
Which design pattern is preferred .So that Main Timer class logic should not be changed in future , even after number of clients who registered for Timer class gets changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observer Pattern using a callback on the observer classes.

```
interface TimerOberserver{
   notify();
}

class ObserverClass implements TimerListener{ ...

class Timer {
  List<TimerListener> allListeners;

  //notfy all listeners 

}
```